# $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$ do not exist, $\lim\limits_{x \to a}[f(x)+g(x)]$ exists, but $g \neq -f$?

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I am tutoring calculus to a friend, and he managed to find an example of two functions $f$, $g$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$ do not exist, but $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ exists. As we discussed making this more general, we noticed that if we took a function $f$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ does not exist, the function $g = -f$ (assuming $\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$ does not exist) would satisfy the condition that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ exists.

To try to extend this even more, we wondered if there were two functions $f$, $g$ such that at some point $a \in \mathbb{R}$, all of the following are satisfied:

1. $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not exist
3. $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ exists
4. $g \neq -f$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Since we haven't discussed infinite limits yet, assume $\left|\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]\right| < \infty$. Are there any examples of $f$, $g$ that satisfy the above four conditions?

As you might guess, none of us were sure where to even begin with this, so unfortunately, I don't have any more thoughts other than the above. I would prefer an answer which would be understandable to someone new to calculus, but if it requires some $\delta$-$\epsilon$, I can try to teach him this as well. The more elementary and motivated the explanation, the better.

Comment: As a starter, any $g=-f+c$ where $c$ is a constant function and $f$ is divergent as $x$ approaches $a$.  In such cases, $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]=c\ne0$.  There are other examples and I'm sure you'll find them as answers.

Comment: Calculus or more properly analysis has so many counter-examples (*counter to what?* perhaps to our expectations / beliefs which are largely the result of years of algebra learnt before calculus) that one should not expect anything to be true unless one has proved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are. The simplest ones (like the one below) might feel a bit like cheating, though, so be warned (I've chosen $a = 0$).
$$
f(x) = \frac1x, \quad g(x) = x-\frac1x
$$
In essence, recognizing that $f+g$ is more or less well-behaved at $x = a$ (or, at least, we allow it to be), but (4) says, right out, that it's not the $0$ function, we just choose some nice function $h(x)$ which is not $0$ everywhere, choose an "ugly" $f(x)$, and make $g(x) = h(x) - f(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can take
$$f (x)=\sin^2 (\frac {1}{x} )$$
$$g (x)=\cos^2 (\frac {1}{x}) $$
$$a=0$$

$$\lim_0 (f (x)+g (x))=1$$
but
$\lim_0 f (x) $ and $\lim_0g (x) $ do not exist.

Comment: Cool with a bounded example. Technically, it falls into the general scheme in my answer (I think all examples do), but I only had infinity in mind when I wrote it.